# How to prevent restart on function submited using dask.distributed.client.Client when the worker gets killed due to asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

How to prevent restart on function submitted using dask.distributed.client.Client when the worker gets killed due to asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError - e.g. OOM (instantiated objects are larger than worker memory)

**Expected behavior:**
Client.submit method has parameter retries that default to 0 -  so I would expect 0 retries

**Observed behavior:**
4 retries of the submitted function before it the dask gives up

**How to reproduce:**

This function causes the issue - the worker gets killed due to the OOM but the function is launched repeatedly

```py
def oom_script():

    def generate_data() -> bytes:
        """something that represents memory allocation"""
        return os.urandom(10) + b":-) " * (100_000_000 // 4)

    oom_list = []

    while True:
        oom_list.append(generate_data)

client.submit(oom_script)
```

This function works as expected - the function raises exception and finishes.

```py
def exception_script():
    raise Exception()

client.submit(exception_script)
```

Comment: Are you saying four workers end up killed, or that a worker restarts four times, and only then the task comes back as failed?

Comment: I have clarified the question, the function is run 4x before it is failed

Comment: I don't gather which of my scenarios that is: does the same worker die, restart and then get the same task again?

Comment: The worker dies (is killed due to OOM), the submitted function is run again (either on restarted worker or another worker)

Answer (score 2):

The default value for `retries` will cover cases when a task fails. In this specific example, what happens is a worker fails before completing the task, which prompts scheduler to restart the worker and attempt the task again.

The relevant configuration here is `distributed.scheduler`'s `allowed-failures` (default value 3, which gives the 4 attempts you mention).

To make sure that in these cases there is no attempt to restart the workers, it's possible to modify the configured values. The example below shows how to do it using a context manager (to change these settings temporarily):

```py
from dask.distributed import Client, as_completed
from dask import config
import os

client = Client(n_workers=1)

def oom_script():

    def generate_data() -> bytes:
        """something that represents memory allocation"""
        return os.urandom(10) + b":-) " * (100_000_000)

    oom_list = []

    while True:
        oom_list.append(generate_data)

with config.set({'distributed.scheduler.allowed-failures': 0}):
    with Client(n_workers=1) as client:
        f = client.submit(oom_script)
        for fut in as_completed([f]):
            print(f.status)
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, however the `config.set(...` does not seem to do the trick for me, the submitted function gets into processing again... Even if I set it globally, maybe it's because I am using dask-kubernetes?

So far I have managed to solve this by inserting a plugin that monitors whether the function gets into processing for 2nd time... which is kinda hacky.

Comment: That's odd, I'd recommend printing the value of `config.config` (it's a dictionary) just before the `client.submit`. This way you can double check that the `allowed-failures` is indeed set to zero. If it is and you are still having trouble, then we have another problem at hand.